# Best approach to File Conversion problems

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have a task that i have to complete. I know the solution but i want to make sure that my solution is according to proper OOP/Design Patterns. Here is the scenerio

1- I have 2 files with different formats. (Lets say FormatA and   FormatB).

2- I want to convert data in FormatA to FormatB.

3- FormatA    is plain text file with keys. Each new line is a new
    key/value pair.    FormatB is XML.

4- The keys in FormatA file can be same as the keys    in FormatB but can also be different. Sometimes we might need to do    some calculations to convert the
    value to FormatB.

5- There are some    chances that more keys will
    be added in future to either the old one    or the new one.

**My solution:**

I want the solution to be generic and no hardcoding. So, that if in future some key mapping change then i should not change the code.

1- First i created a "Mapping" XML file that has all the data that which key in FormatA maps to which field in FormatB. The XML structure is something like this

```
//oldKey = name of the key in the old file format
//newKey = name of the key in the new format
//ignore = optional. set it to true if you want to ignore this field during conversion
//function = optional.Name of a function that will be called. This function will have all the logic to do the calculations
//functionparams = optinal .key names from the old file that need calculation
//defaultvalue = optional parameter. This value will be replaced no matter what if given.

<field oldKey="abc" newKey="def" ignore="false" function="MultiplyBy2" functionparams="abc" defaultvalue="4">
```

2- I created a class named "TextFileParser" that loads the text file and creates a dictionary with all the keys.

3- I created a class named "MappingXMLParser" which loads the Mapping XML file and populates a dictionary with all the data.

3- I created a class "TextFileToXML" that uses the above 2 classes to write the data in the XML file. No composition is used.

4- I created a class named "Conversion". If the Mapping XML file has declared some function (like "MultiplyBy2") then the definition of functions will be in this class. I will use reflection to call the methods of this class from the class "TextFileToXML".

This is my design but i donot know that it is correct in terms of OOP/Design Patterns/architecture. Can you point out the mistakes ? What can be done better or any good approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably understand, there is no such thing as **correct** design. I would suggest following standard practices. I would follow these steps:

1. Translate the key-value file to a simple XML file following the simplest possible XML schema
2. I would use an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) to describe the translation between the simple XML files generated in step 1, and the final result.
3. Execute the transformation described in XSLT using an XML operations library. I suppose you could find one, on the specific programming language you use.

This way, in case of changing something (adding more keys in future, changing the target XML schema etc), you would only have to change the translation process described in XSLT, which is not application code but an XML file. You have nothing regarding the specific translation process hard-coded in your application.

Regarding the overall design, I would choose to use the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). I think it matches perfectly your situation.

Hope I helped!